# I upgraded quarkus from 2.15.3 to 3.2.2 quarkus:dev works fine and native build also builds fine but when ever i try to execute the jar I get error

Tags: graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

I updated quarkus from 2.15.3 to 3.2.2 `quarkus:dev` works fine and native build also builds fine with `mvn package -Dnative` and creates runner.jar file but when ever i try to execute the jar with `java -jar applicationRunner.jar`  I get error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Unsafe.java:1160)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.ensureClassInitialized(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:300)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodHandleAccessorFactory.newConstructorAccessor(MethodHandleAccessorFactory.java:103)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:236)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.acquireConstructorAccessor(Constructor.java:546)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:496)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/graalvm/nativeimage/ImageInfo
        at io.quarkus.runtime.ImageMode.current(ImageMode.java:40)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.logging.LoggingSetupRecorder.initializeLoggingForImageBuild(LoggingSetupRecorder.java:522)        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LoggingResourceProcessor$setupLoggingStaticInit2062061316.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LoggingResourceProcessor$setupLoggingStaticInit2062061316.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.graalvm.nativeimage.ImageInfo
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoa
```

I tried adding the  org.graalvm.nativeimage.ImageInfo to reflection but noticed that during build it says that that class was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever figured it out, but I had a very similar issue and was able to resolve it by removing a dependency (`camel-quarkus-xml-jaxb` in my case). This was reflected in a couple of the log lines, similar to ones in yours that come from the `io.quarkus.runtime.logging.LoggingSetupRecorder` that for whatever reason seems to think that it had been built for native and was looking for that `org.graalvm.nativeimage.ImageInfo` class.

Just thought I'd post a note in case others come across a similar problem.